# how to show in Google Ads always the close button?

Tags: reactjs, ads, google-ads-api, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

I've been required to add a Google Ad Banner to a website built in react, redux, typescript.

The problem I got is that the close button doesn't appear all the time. just randomly. most of the time you can see the button adChoices.

Image with close button:
[image: Image with close button]

what I normally get:[image: what I normally get]

Does anyone know how to force the Ad to show all the time this close button.

I have an example here using react and react-dfp:

https://codesandbox.io/s/xpxwoo1nk4